# Why this function never ends if I am using ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, python-requests, threadpoolexecutor

I wanted to create some sort of timeout for this function but it doesn't end in any case, can someone point me in the right direction on how i could kill this function when I want?
The code is basically a web crawler.

```
def StartCrawler(base_link, timeout):
Session = requests.Session()
global LINKS_LIST
LINKS_LIST.put(base_link)
HASH_CODES.add(CreateHash(base_link))
start_time = time.time()
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=35) as executor:
    while time.time() - start_time <= timeout:
        try:
            target_url = LINKS_LIST.get()
            executor.submit(GetSessionLinks, Session, target_url)
        except:
            print("error")
            continue
```

Comment: Is `time.time() - start_time` ever less than `timeout`?

Comment: @wwii yes, why it wouldn’t?

Comment: `...it doesn't end in any case...` - You said that it never ended so I was wondering.